# Jasmine test cases for inner function calls returning response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write the jasmine test case for a function which in turn calls another function and returns a response. Seems like the function is called but i am not getting the value that is set inside the function.

Controller Function:

```
 angular.module('serviceApp')
.controller('startWorkscopeCtrl', function ($rootScope, $log, $scope, CommentService) {

    $scope.getTextById = function (id) {
        CommentService.get({ id: id }, function (response) {
            $scope.text = response;
            $scope.textCount = $scope.text.length;
        });
    };
 });
```

The service is referenced in another js file where it makes the rest service call to the backend service.

```
angular.module('restServiceModule', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('CommentService', function($resource){
    return $resource(
        {
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                url: window.urlPrefix + '/commentservice/:id',
                params: {
                    id: '@id'
                }
            }

        });
    })
```

Test Case:

```
var mockTextComment;
var fakeText = ['testPass'];     
beforeEach(function(){
    mockTextComment = {
        get: function(){
            return fakeText;
        }
    };
}); 

it('should get comments by asset id', function () {
    spyOn(mockTextComment, 'get');

    inject(function ($controller) {
        ctrl = $controller('startWorkscopeCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            CommentService: mockTextComment
        });

        scope.getTextById(40107);
        expect(scope.textCount).toEqual(1);

    });
});
```

With this, i am getting the below error:

```
**Expected undefined to equal 1.
Error: Expected undefined to equal 1.**
```

Not sure where i am doing wrong. Any pointers on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `CommentService.get` does not return a value; it calls back a function upon completion. Therefore, a `CommentService` mock would look like this:

```
var mock = {
    get : function(arg1, callback){
        callback(fakeText);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried the above but having the same issue with callback.

Comment: is the callback called?

Comment: no, the callback is not getting called. i put a logger inside the above get function but it is not getting printed in the console.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of the controller? Or at least the part of the code where I can see how the controller gets the CommentService.

Comment: I have edited my original code including the controller part and the service call part as well.

Comment: If you post a plnkr that reproduces the problem I will have a look at it.